# Opacity control for overlaying plots

Tags: graphics, wolfram-mathematica

Given two vector plots and a contour plot like the following

```
as = VectorPlot[{Cos[y], Sin[x] }, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
                 VectorScale -> Automatic, VectorColorFunction -> "Rainbow"
     ];
bs = StreamPlot[{Cos[y], Sin[x] }, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
                 VectorScale -> Automatic, StreamColorFunction -> "Rainbow"
     ];
cs = ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Sin[y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
                 ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"
     ];
Show[cs, bs, as]
```

[image]

we can see basic superimposing job is well done by Show[]. But my question is **how can I control the opacity of the background contour plot** cs? Also, how can I insert "BlueGreenYellow" type color schemes in a color function like the following?

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Sin[y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
            ColorFunction -> (Directive[Opacity[#],Blue] &)
];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try using `BaseStyle` as follows:

```
cs = ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Sin[y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
                 ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", 
                 BaseStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5]]
     ];
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

I do not believe that jmlopez' solution is correct, because the vectors and the frame are also partially transparent.  I believe that it is better to insert an `Opacity` command into the `Graphics` object, which will preserve opaque vectors:

```
as = VectorPlot[{Cos[y], Sin[x]}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
       VectorScale -> Automatic, VectorColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];
bs = StreamPlot[{Cos[y], Sin[x]}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
       VectorScale -> Automatic, StreamColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];
cs = ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Sin[y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
       ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"];

cs2 = MapAt[{Opacity[0.5], #} &, cs, 1];

Show[cs2, bs, as]
```

[image]

---

The second question was never addressed.  You can combine opacity and a color gradient like this:

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Sin[y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  ColorFunction -> ({Opacity[#], ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"][#]} &)
]
```

[image]